# Maven Spring dependency repository

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies, repository

I am developing a Spring application using Maven and I would like to find the most comprehensive and up-to-date repository with the most dependencies. So far I have found three repos, but I am unsure of which one to use.

- http://search.maven.org/
- http://mvnrepository.com/
- http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/search

Comment: Are you missing some deps from [Central](http://search.maven.org) ?

Comment: Do you plan to use all th dependencies possible? Why don't you decide what you need as dependencies, and the look for a repo containing it?

Comment: This might help http://www.springsource.org/node/2962

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/) is the most comprehensive repository as it contains artifacts from a lot of projects.

The Central Repository is also the default repository used by [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) when no other repositories are defined in a project's POM.  As such, the repository does not need to be explicitly configured in a POM in order for it to be used.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most comprehensive repo is Maven's default Central Repository - 
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2